# Get child props in Jest? (NO ENZYME)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to test whether a React button component's text changes on-click. This is roughly what gets returned inside the component I'm testing (let's call it RandComponent):

```
   return (<>
      ...
      <ButtonComponent
         data-testid='testButton'
      >
         {getButtonText()}
      </ButtonComponent>
   </>)
```

I want to be able to access whatever getButtonText() returns in Jest. I've looked online and in enzyme you can do something like this in the test file:

```
   it('test button text toggle', async ()=>{
      let container;
      await act(async ()=> container = render(<RandComponent/>));      
      
      const button = getByTestId('testButton');
      expect(button.text()).toEqual(whatever getButtonText() is supposed to return);
     
   }
```

My problem is that I can't use enzyme... is there a way to get the child prop text like in the last line (button.text()) in Jest?

Comment: Are you using `react-testing-library`?

Answer (score 0):

This requires to stub `ButtonComponent` by means of Jest and assert props that were provided to it:

```
jest.mock('...ButtonComponent module...', () => jest.fn());

...

let buttonProps;
ButtonComponent.mockImplementation(props => {
  buttonProps = props;
  return <div>ButtonComponent</div>
});
container = render(<RandComponent/>));
...
expect(buttonProps.children).toBe(...);
```

This is boilerplate code that Enzyme is supposed to save from.